# multiple MPMoviePlayerController on a tableview

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have multiple `MPMoviePlayerController` on a `UITableView` (on different sections).

I know that only one can play on a specific time, but the thing is that if a different player was in "pause" mode, it gets stuck and I need to re-init it.

I can do a sophisticated `[tableview reload]` on everything else but me - but it seems cycle consuming and idiotic (and not that simple to reload all but me)

Is there a better way? Maybe a 3rd party OS package that does handle this nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all, why you need multiple `MPMoviePlayerController` instances if you play only one video at a time? You could create one instance of `MPMoviePlayerController` to play all videos one by one.

And, I think, `AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerLayer` would be more extensible solution for playing videos on iOS. Take a look at the `AVFoundation` framework reference for more information about the `AVPlayer` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html).

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried a single MPMoviePlayerController. But when a user pauses a video he sees it in a different cell...
Tried to avoid the work of rolling my own with AVPlayer...

Comment: but now I see on a random tutorial that it is not as bad as it sounds... thanks

Comment: And now - I see that AVPlayer has no controls... Is there no real alternative?

Comment: Ok, if the user pauses, and plays another video in different cell, just recreate, or set another video url to the `MPMoviePlayerController `(sorry, I'm not sure about this, used it a long ago, but I'm sure you can use one instance at a time). And, yes you are right, using `AVPlayer` for playing video is not hard, I would say it's very easy, and you can use your own controls, but it would be very extensible, in design and usage matters.